# Why does this code throw a java.lang.StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

This is the code:

The array initialization

```
int candy = new int[ratings.length];
```

The for loop

```
for (int i=0;i<ratings.length;i++){
    count += calculate(i);
}
```

The calculate method

```
public int calculate(int num){
        if (candy[num] != 0){  //the kid's candy number has already been calculated
            return candy[num];
        } else if (type(num) == 1){  //type A
    candy[num]=1;  //store it in the array, save time for re-calculate
            return 1;
        } else if (type(num) == 2){  //type B
            candy[num] = calculate(num+1)+1;
            return candy[num];
        } else if (type(num) == 3){  //type C
            candy[num] = calculate(num-1)+1;
            return candy[num];
        } else if (type(num) == 4){  //type D
            candy[num] = max(calculate(num-1)+1, calculate(num+1)+1);
            return candy[num];
        }
        return 0;  //should never reach here
}
```

I use this calculate method in a for loop, iterate num from 1-12000, then I got a java.lang.StackOverflowError.

Then I change the code from

```
    candy[num] = calculate(num+1)+1;
    return candy[num];
```

to

```
    int value1 = calculate(num+1)+1;
    candy[num] = value1;
    return value1;
```

There's no error. I don't know why? Please help me out.

Comment: We need your `for` loop, your `array` declaration and initialization in order to help you. Thanks to add code to your question.

Comment: You have infinite recursive function calls. Give special attention to base cases !

Comment: Looks like you have an endless loop.

Comment: What is the definition of `type()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a recursive loop.  The `calculate` method calls itself in a couple of places with arguments based on `num`.  If the logic is incorrect, you end up with an infinite recursive loop.  In Java that will result in a `StackOverflowError`.

It is not clear why this is happening because you haven't provided all of the relevant code.  But don't!  You should be able to debug this for yourself.

You need to use the debugger in your IDE.

- set a breakpoint at the start of the `calculate` method
- run the program in debug mode
- when the program hist the breakpoint, it will stop
- examine the variables
- single-step to see what `type` is returning
- etcetera ...